# How to load jqgrid on button click and send parameters to the action in jqGrid 4.6.0 in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I want to load every year's data in jqgrid when I click on a button and after loading a modal form and selecting the year from drop down list. [a diagram of the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkT5I.png) 
but i don't know how to do this.

And this is my source code :

```
<!-- Page content -->
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width: 100%">

    <div class="container" style="width:40%;margin-top:2%">

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Filter</a>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content"> 
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a href="#" dir="ltr" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="modal-body"> 
                        <form id="myForm" dir="rtl"> 
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Year</label> 
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YEAR_ABBR, ViewBag.YearList as MultiSelectList, "--select--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlYear", multiple = "multiple" })
                            </div> 

                        </form> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                        <input type="reset" value="GetRep" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" />

                    </div>   </div> 
            </div>    </div>    </div>

    <div dir="rtl" align="center" style="overflow:auto" class="tablecontainer">
        <div id="rsperror"></div> 
        <table id="list" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
        <div id="pager" style="text-align:center;"></div>
    </div>
```

Now my script is something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () { 
                bindData();
                $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {  
                        $('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');   }) 
        }); 
        var bindData = function () {

            $('#list').jqGrid({ 
                url: '@Url.Action("Get_RepContracts","Home")', 
                postData:  {  YEAR_ABBR: function () { return $('#YEAR_ABBR').val(); }   },
                datatype: 'json',
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "Rows",
                    page: "Page", 
                }, 
                mtype: 'GET',
                //columns names
                colNames: ['Vahed_Descript'   ], 
                colModel: [
    { name: 'Vahed_Descript', index: 'Vahed_Descript', align: 'right', width: 200, sorttype: "number",    }  
        ],
        pager: $('#pager'),
       rowNum: 800,
        rowList: [ 800 ,1000],
        sortname: 'Vahed_Descript',   
        hidegrid: false,
        direction: "rtl",
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        footerrow: true,
        userDataOnFooter: true,
        loadComplete: function () {
            calculateTotal();
            $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#E0E0E0");
        },
        loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
            jQuery("#rsperror").html("Type: " + st + "; Response: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }   , loadonce: true 
        })   ;
```

And here the button code  (  My modal form works well. when I click the filter button, the filter options in my modal form appear, and then I select the year from year dropdownlist in modal and then i click the report button, after that the below code fires and I can see the selected year's data in  action "Get_RepContracts" but it does not bind to my jqgrid):

Thanks in Advance...

UPDATE : Now My code is like below :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
                bindData();

       $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
         var myPostData = $('#list').jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
                    $('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                })    });

        var bindData = function () {

            $('#list').jqGrid({  
                url: '@Url.Action("Get_RepContracts","Home")',  
                postData: {
                   YEAR_ABBR : function () { return $("#YEAR_ABBR").val();}, 
                 } , 
                datatype: 'json',
                jsonReader: { ........
```

Comment: `$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid")` and in the grid part add this         `,beforeRequest: function () {
            jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { year: $('#year').val() } });
        }`

Comment: The above was an example of how to send parameters to the server via the jqGrid ajax request. Obviously the year parameter will probably vary for you.

Comment: @Steve Thank you so much for your answer , but I don't know why it did not work for me.

Comment: Use the F12 console to work out what's going in. Is your javascript being called? is your ajax being posted?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you , Yeah, It is called perfectly every time i click the filter button and even I can see the selected year's data in the action , but I don't know why it's not being binded to jqGrid.

Comment: So in the network tab when you click on the ajax post and check the reponse, there is data there in the format that you expect?

Comment: If `bindData();` is what binds the data then that needs to go into `success`. You have it outside the ajax call at the moment so it's just going to run it without waiting

Comment: All your ajax does is calls a web endpoint and hides some divs. It doesn't do anything with the data that is returned. Let me go check some of my old code

Comment: I believe you need to use the jqGrid `postData` property _inside_ the jqGrid definition. This lets you dynamically attach parameters to the jqGrid data url. So you could use postdata to add the year as a parameter to the jgGrid post. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149747/jqgrid-set-focus-to-clicked-cell-and-implement-datepicker-in-ie-and-firefox is an example of automatically adding a parameter `startDate` to the jgGrid post. This way you don't need to have the seperate ajax call.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you so much for the answers, yes, bindData()  is what binds the data and that needs to go into success and I think I used it in a wrong way.If i don't use a seperate ajax call then how to open popup form?? because i have many filter options in that form .

Comment: Can you edit your question and clarify what you have achieved? I thought you had he modal form sorted out but looking at your code you don't, right? You need to clarify what you've managed so far, otherwise I will make incorrect assumptions

Comment: The first thing you need to do is confirm you can use the `postData` property. Add it to your jQuery initialisation with a hard coded value and confirm it works. Then use a hidden div and confirm that works. Then set your hidden div from your popup

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you so much ,I edited my question, ( My modal form works well. when I click the filter button, the filter options in my modal form appear, and then I select the year from year dropdownlist in modal and then i click the report button, after that the below code fires and I can see the selected year's data in action "Get_RepContracts" but it does not bind to my jqgrid)

Comment: Glad your modal works. Now try using the  postdata property as described in my prior comment. This is how I would make it work: 1. User sets year in modal popup. 2. Ok pressed in modal popup. 3. Modal popup calls refresh method on jqgrid. 4. In jqgrid, Postdata refers to year field in modal, so when it’s refreshed it passes the year parameter. That’s how I’ve done it in the past and it works.

Comment: You’re getting your Ajax mixed up. Jqgrid already uses Ajax to populate. You just need to refresh it and make sure your year parameter is in postdata. Take a look at my question that I linked to. It uses postdata and refers to a field. That’s what you need to do. All your modal popup should do is call refresh on jqgrid. It shouldn’t call GetRepcontracts at all. There might be a way to bind it like you want but I wouldn’t know how to do that.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am really Thankful, But I tried the steps you said in the comment and again it did not work . when I pass OK in modal nothing happens. (I edited my question to show how I used postdata)

Comment: Please do not say 'not work'. This is a particuarly irksome expression for me. Instead please explain what happened - did you see no change in the grid? You need to use F12 console to decipher what is happening. Lastly, your modal dialog just needs to trigger the grid refresh. The OK button should hide the modal and just call `$('#list').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135171/how-to-refresh-the-data-in-a-jqgrid

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I edited the script in my question.  I appreciate it if you take a look at it. I think I used it in a wrong way.After clicking OK the modal form doesn't close  and data doesn't change.

Comment: You probably have a JavaScript error. What does the F12 console say? What happens when you step through the script?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid sorry for asking too much, i am still working on my problem , I understood that i had loadonce: true. that was why my grid reload did not work. now reload works but it does not send the year parameter to my action and my modal form does not close. can you help on this issue, please?

Comment: With regards to hiding the modal, I don't see any code to hide it. Does the Cancel button hide it? if so, maybe you need to add `data-dismiss="modal"` to the GetRep button also (if you are using bootstrap to manage all this). With regards to the grid refreshing, is it calling the web service? I can't see what's going on, that why you really need to use the F12 console. Go the network tab and see if the grid is calling the web service to get data or not.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you , with this code : $("#myModal").modal("hide"); Now the modal hides perfectly. But still year parameter is null , and network tab does not show anything. I mean when I debug it goes to my action (means it is calling the web service) but parameters are null.  I can send you a pic on what network tab is showing.

Comment: I've looked at my working code and in order to get the selected value out of a dropdown I use `$("select#YEAR_ABBR option:selected").val()`. So... when your modal is up, press F12 and in the javascript console type `$('#YEAR_ABBR').val()`. Do you see anything? What about `$("select#YEAR_ABBR option:selected").val()`? At this point we need to confirm what javascript correctly scrapes the year out of your drop down

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am really sorry, I think I am taking your time too much. in both cases it says undefined.

Comment: @sam: Is the id `YEAR_ABBR` correct (see `return $("#YEAR_ABBR").val();`)? You use `@id = "ddlYear"` as a parameter of `@Html.DropDownListFor`. It seems to me that you need just change `return $("#YEAR_ABBR").val();` to `return $("#ddlYear").val();`

Comment: @Oleg Thank you so much, It was exactly What the problem was. It worked perfectly : return $("#ddlYear").val();   vielen dank

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank You so much. you Helped me so much.

Comment: @Oleg Thousands times thanks , again.

Comment: @sam: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have small problem with the usage of correct id of select element. Your HTML code contains `@id = "ddlYear"` parameter of `@Html.DropDownListFor`:

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.YEAR_ABBR,
    ViewBag.YearList as MultiSelectList,
    "--select--",
    new {
        @class = "form-control",
        @id = "ddlYear",
        multiple = "multiple"
    }
)
```

but you still use

```js
postData: {
    YEAR_ABBR: function () { return $("#YEAR_ABBR").val(); }
}
```

To solve the problem you should just modify the code to

```js
postData: {
    YEAR_ABBR: function () { return $("#ddlYear").val(); }
}
```